# Foundation 5 / Reveal modal error / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 for my web application. Now when I try to call a modal I am getting JS-error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of undefined "**

in the console. I am not able to find any possible fix for this even in foundation blog/support.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.css">
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <title>Test code</title>
</head>
<body> 
      <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal>Click Me For A Modal</a>

        <div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
      <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
      <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
      <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script> 

     <script>
      $(document).foundation();
      /*Fix for Sticky footer and List to Be displayed properly in Sidebar*/          
      $(function() {
        var timer;
        $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.inner-wrap').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px" );
            }, 40);
        }).resize();
      });
    </script>
    <!-- Modal -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with this example is that your data-reveal-id="myModal" attribute doesn't match the reveal modal's id="firstModal" attribute. Once those match up you should no longer see this error.

Also, your anchor tag doesn't need the data-reveal attribute, only the modal itself needs that.

@BobbySales: Other things can cause this too... like if you mistype your **data-reveal** attribute. If the data-reveal attribute is missing or the data-reveal-id doesn't match the id of the modal then this will break. If you're opening your modal with javascript and you get this error, make sure you don't have a typo in your data-reveal attribute. Another thing that can cause this is if the **$(document).foundation()** call happens before the modal is displayed on the page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you @jphase. in my case problem was id miss match

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if your target div is missing the `data-reveal` attribute.